# How to change the desktop envoirment in xrdp? [20.04]

Tags: gnome, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I have a server with a gui version of Ubuntu installed. I have installed xrdp in order to access it from windows. I had done the same thing once before and when I connected with windows it displayed the normal gnome desktop. When I did it this time it only showed xfce. If I remove xfce than my rdp connection crashes when connecting. How do I get gnome/normal ubuntu desktop envoirment back in xrdp?

Answer (score -1):

Run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` for the default one,

Or `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` for Ubuntu flavoured GNOME

Or `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` for Ubuntu flavoured Unity desktop.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.450.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` @JanezKranjski

Comment: i tried installing the desktop and reinstalling, rebooted... Still didn't work tho.  I have checked `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` and it says it's using gnome-session but it displays xfce

Comment: Reboot. When it asks you to enter your password, press the gear icon and select Ubuntu Desktop @JanezKranjski

Comment: I can't get to the login screen. I only have the rdp login screen and then I am in the xfce. If I remove the xfce than it just closes after connecting. I have also tried this(https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17175) but it didnt really do anything.

Comment: If you are using RDP, then you can just go to the physical Ubuntu machine and select Ubuntu Desktop there